# Django SqlServer Improperly configured - settings.DATABASES

Tags: python, sql-server, django, apache, pyodbc

Earlier i had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643494/error-loading-pyodbc-module-while-running-on-apache) with my pyodbc module, that did not run my application on the apache server, running on my windows machine. I found to solve my problem of getting the django project to run on apache using [this hint](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=214).

But now I am facing a bit of a different problem. The django application runs on apache but throws this error on the page.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /auth/login/
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

***Just to be clear, this project runs perfectly when deployed through djangos inbuilt server.*** This is how my database connection looks like in the settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'myDbName',
        'USER': 'myusername',    
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'driver': 'SQL Native Client',
            'dsn': 'test',
            'MARS_Connection': True,
        },
    },    
}
```

UPDATE:

I updated my code according to [Django MSSQL Documentation](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/en/1.2/settings.html), ran into a few problems and got it to work by updating my pywin32 ***And again this works on djangos inbuilt server and NOT APACHE giving me the same ImproperlyConfigured error***

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'myDbName',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'MYHOST',
        'USER': 'myusername',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'provider': 'SQLNCLI11', 
            'use_mars': False,
        },
    }
}
```

My system - Windows 7, Apache 2.2, python 2.7, django 1.4.2, pyodbc-3.0.6.win32-py2.7

Any hints or tips towards this is highly appriciated, i ahve been trying to get this project up and running for quite some time now.

Thanks alot

Comment: Is Apache running on the same machine with access to the same Python packages?

Comment: Yes, previously I have created demo django apps, that say "It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page."  and they ran perfectly using Apache.

Comment: Were you using a different database engine in those cases?

Comment: In one of them I used the "sqlite3" and the other I used the "sql_server.pyodbc". But now I am starting to have a funny feelings if its got something to do with versions, cuz this project was initially built on django 1.3 and I moved it to 1.4, changing the structure and everything, works fine on djangos inbuilt server, Wonder if something else that's missing in the settings.py

Comment: I manage to get it work, it was to do with my DSN configuration. Had to give the database username and password while creating it, kinda funny i idid not have that problem while running it on djangos inbuilt server

Comment: It would be great if you could post that as an answer to your own question and accept it so others can see how you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question might be a bit wierdbut hey this is how i got things to work on my machine.

The main problem I had was that my DSN was not getting connected with the django project, in the steps I have mentioned below, its the last step that made the whole difference in making it work. Previously I had selected *"With integrated Windows authentication"* while creating my DSN, but surprisingly it worked when I was running it using djangos inbuilt server.

- Open the app ODBC Data Source Administrator in Windows 7 (search ODBC from Start Menu).
- Under System DSN tab, click the Add button.
- Select SQL Server Native Client 10.0
- Enter DSN **your_dsn_name**, description(optional), and the SQL Server to connect , click Next
- Select option “With SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user”.
- Enter Login ID ('**your_username**’) and password ('**your_password**’). Click Next, Next and Finish.

And i changed my database connection back to the original code

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'MaDaMa_App',
        'USER': 'your_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_password',
        'HOST': 'MYHOST',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'driver': 'SQL Native Client',
            'dsn': 'your_dsn_name',
            'MARS_Connection': True,
        },
    },
 }
```

Thanks to all who helped me solve this, and hope this is helpfull for someone out there.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a built-in backend, you should specify database engine as given below:

```
'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql'
```

If you are not using a built-in backend you should specify a fully-qualified path (i.e. `mypackage.backends.whatever`) in the `ENGINE` setting. Information on defining database backend in given in [django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#engine).

Update:
You can try using [django-mssql](https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql) for using sql-server with django and the clear documentation is available [here in readthedocs](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org).

Comment: I am using a "sql-server" backend not mysql. Using 'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc', works when i run the project with djangos' inbuilt server.

Comment: @shabeer90 If you are not using a built-in backend, you should specify the exact location of the package which is to be used.

Comment: I'm not pretty much sure about it. You can try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/842831/1095090).

Comment: Tried using the link you sent me. Works fine while using djangos inbuilt server, BUT DOES NOT RUN ON APACHE :|